# hasMany with default in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel - Is there a way to return a diffent collection if a relationship does not return any values?

Eg.

```php
class Topic 
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Questions::class);
    }
}
```

This return the questions for the topic. But the required behaviour I need is if I query `$topic->questions()` is for it to return me a list of

```php
return Questions::get()->whereNull('topic_id')
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

The migrations:

```php
Schema::create('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('topic')->index();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('topic_id')
        ->nulluble()
        ->comment('link to the topic table');
    $table->foreign('topic_id', 'fk_topic_question')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('topics')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->string('question')->nullable();

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And then default questions seed example:

```php
$data = [
    [
        'question'=>'default questions 1'
    ],
    [
        'question'=>'default questions 2'
    ]
];

Questions::insert($data);
```

Comment: share your migrations and what you have done so far so to test it.

Comment: so you want to add a condition to the query that returns only where null `topic_id`? kinda defeats the purpose of the relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on a interim solution (bit hacky but does what I need) :

```
public function getQuestions()
    {
        if ($this->questions()->exists()) {
            return $this->questions;
        } else {
            return Question::all();
        }
    }
```

then I use `$topic->getQuestions()` instead of `$topic->questions()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `optional` helper function:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional

create a topic for default questions and relate defualt questions to this topic and then you can use this:

```
$questions = optional($preferTopic,$defaultTopic)->questions;
```

Comment: this will work but does not do what I need. I am contrained on the DB due to it not being used by Laravel API only.